# Checking if drag is on drop from button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I understand the logistic of jQuery Ui and I have managed to create drag and drops well. However, I am having a problem in trying to check if a drag is on a drop from a button press. Here is some pseudo code of what I am trying to achieve

```
function checkAnswers(){ (called on button press)

If(Drag 2 is on Drop 1){
    (Drag 2).css('color', 'green')
}

If(Drag 3 or Drag 4  is on Drop 1){
    (Drag 3/4).css('color', 'red')
}
```

Apologies forgot to mention this is javascript

Comment: what kind of language are you coding??? Irrelevant pseudo code doesn't help much...

Comment: Apologies. Forgot to mention it is javascript

Comment: @Robb The problem is i'm not sure how to code this from a button click. How can we say Drag 2 is ON drop 1 for example

Comment: Consider: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-over

Comment: @Robb but 'over' has to be done at the time when the drag is dropped right? I would like to check if a drag is on a drop at a later time (button press)

Comment: Beware ! You must check the behaviour of a simple drag and drop. Does it move the dragged element in the dom or does it just affect a absolute position ? If you want to make a Q/A check, where answer are dragged, you'd better do some stuff in the `.drop()` method. So you can be sure that the dragged element has been moven in the dom. If so, it's really easy to check if elements are relatives to each other.

Comment: @TCHdvlp Thanks for this. Would you be able to elaborate a little further. Im basically making something where words are placed into categories (droppable boxes). When the button is pressed it checks if they are in the correct category and colours them accordingly.

Comment: The approach wont be the same if you have only one button for testing a bucket of questions or if you have several ones. Also, do you only need to count the number of good answer or do you need to know wich answer is wrong. You must develop your post if you need more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to rig up something like this:

```
$("#draggable").draggable();
$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function () {
        alert("dropped");
    },
    over: function () {
        $( "#droppable" ).droppable( "option", "hoverClass", "drop-hover" );
    },
    out: function () {
        $( "#droppable" ).droppable( "option", "hoverClass", "" );
    },
    hoverClass: "drop-hover"
});
$("#btn").click(  function () {
    var hoverClass = $("#droppable").droppable( "option", "hoverClass" );    
    console.log(hoverClass);
    if(hoverClass === 'drop-hover') {
        console.log("hovered");
    } else {
        console.log("not hovered");
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9DVN2/4/)